# Как искать категорий в WP_Query когда включен плагин Polylang?

Tags: wordpress, polylang

У меня появилась одна небольшая проблема 
когда я пытаюсь произвести поиск при помощи WP_Query

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 5, 
'order'=> 'DESC',
'lang' => '',
// или 'category_name' => 'red',
// или 'cat' => get_cat_ID('red'),
// или 'cat' => 276,
'post_type' => 'post'
);
WP_Query( $args );
```

Он не может нечего найти так как категория существует на разных языках. red-ru, red-en.
проблема не распространяется на категорий у которых только один язык 
Если у кого советы как это решить?

Comment: Ничего не понятно.. Стандартный поиск ищет по контенту.  Т.е. по всем постам. Причем тут вообще полиланг и рубрики (а не "категории").

Comment: @SeVlad В wordpress категорий переведены как рубрики. так что рубрики и категорий это одно и то же. я обвел их в комментарий что бы не писать несколько раз что я перепробовал. не по id не по имени он не может найти посты.

Comment: Если в твоём wordpress-е написано ["категории" вместо "рубрики"](https://translate.wordpress.org/locale/ru/default/glossary) - выкинь го и возьми правильный. Может и проблему заодно решишь.